# How can I use shared_ptr of boost in this situation?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have 2 classes, **A** and **B**.

In class A, I have a pointer on B called Bptr.

I allocate memory for Bptr in the constructor of A, and I free memory of Bptr in A's destructor.

```
class B {
//whatever
public:
    B(int,int);
}

class A {
private:
    B * Bptr;
public:
    A();
}

A::A(){
    Bptr = new B(2,5);
}

A::~A(){
    delete Bptr;
}
```

How can I integrate Boost in my code and use the smart pointer : **boost::shared_ptr** ? How would my code look like?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) ?  I'm a little confused about what exactly it is you are wondering about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class B {
//whatever
public:
    B(int,int);
}

class A {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<B> Bptr;
public:
    A();
}

A::A(){
    Bptr = boost::make_shared<B>(2,5);
}

A::~A(){
  // Bptr automatically deleted if this is the only boost::shared_ptr pointing to it
}
```

Although you *could* simply use `new B(2,5)` instead of `boost::make_shared<B>`, the latter is exception-safe.

Comment: Can you clarify the condition : "if this is the only boost::shared_ptr pointing to it"? If it's not the only one, how can I deal with? Notice: I'm in a multi-threading context. Thanks!

Comment: @user1459961: If it's not the only owner, then destroying it just releases its share of the ownership without deleting the object. The object will be deleted when the last shared pointer is destroyed. You shouldn't have to do anything to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first question to ask yourself: why do you want to dynamically allocate the object in the first place? Can you just replace the pointer with a member of type `B`?

Assuming there is a good reason, then why `shared_ptr` (rather than `scoped_ptr` or, in modern C++, `unique_ptr`)? Why do you need shared ownership?

Once you've answered these questions, and determined that shared ownership is the right solution, just replace `B*` with a shared pointer, initialise it in the constructor, and get rid of the redundant destructor (assuming it's not needed for anything else).

```
class A {
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<B> Bptr;
public:
    A() : Bptr(boost::make_shared<B>(2,5)) {}
};
```

You could simply initialise it with a pointer, `Bptr(new B(2,5))`, but using `make_shared` makes more efficient use of memory and (in more complicated situations than this) makes it easier to ensure exception safety.

Comment: +1 for the clever questions. My boss said it's for multi-threading. I didn't verify if he's right in that.

Comment: For the use, it would : Bptr->B_attribute_1, having B_attribute_1 a public attribute of B, right? Thanks

Comment: @user1459961: Yes, smart pointers provide `*` and `->` operators, so they can be dereferenced like regular pointers.